# Touch code only working at center of screen in my ball game using libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

My score does not increment after I touch the ball. It increments only when I touch the ball and its near the center of my screen. 
When my ball only moves in x axis keeping y constant the touch works fine. But when both are incremented the score increases only when touched at the center.

```
@Override
public void render () {


    batch.begin();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.draw(ball,xposi,yposi,100,100);

    if(gameState==1) {


        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

            tmp = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            textureBounds = new Rectangle(xposi, yposi, 100, 100);

            if (textureBounds.contains(tmp.x, tmp.y)) {
                Gdx.app.log("Click", "On Ball");
                score++;
                } 
           else {
                Gdx.app.log("Click", "Not on Ball");
                }
            }



        font.draw(batch, String.valueOf(score), 100, 300);
        font.draw(batch, String.valueOf(lives), 200, 300);

        xposi+=velocity;
        yposi+=velocity;

        if (xposi >= xmax - 100) {

            velocity = -velocity;
        } else if (xposi <= xmin) {

            velocity = -velocity;
        }

        if (yposi >= ymax - 100) {

            velocity = -velocity;
        } else if (yposi <= ymin) {

            velocity = -velocity;
        }

        batch.end();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In libgdx, when we draw something on screen then the screen origin is bottom left corner but when we detect touch then screen origin is top left corner.

When you deal with horizontal movement then there is no involvement of y coordinate so it's work fine. You detect touch on ball when your ball is in center then the value of `Gdx.input.getY()` is approximately same to `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY()` so sometimes works.

so simple solution is just invert touch coordinate origin to bottom left corner.

```
tmp = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
```

**Recommendation :**

Don't create object in render method like you're creating object of Rectangle and Vector3, create object in `show()` or `create()` method and set value to these variable in `render()` method.

Comment: You can just use `camera.unproject()` as stated in the [docs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html)

Comment: @LeonZ. I think owner of this question not using any camera.

Comment: And about your recommendation  did you mean I should do it like this :                  tmp.set(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
    textureBounds.set(xposi,yposi,100,100);

Comment: @Shubhankar ya that's better option according to me, creation of a new object is very painful.

Comment: Hi again Abhishek, I wanted to increase velocity of the ball after click I tried adding if(velocity<0) velocity -= velocity else velocity +=velocity   in my afterTouch code  but it is showing not expected behavior. Please suggest how to implement this. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Shubhankar Increase value of velocity after touch like velocity++