# How to change Sprite on Touch

Tags: android, libgdx

I am new to Libgdx and i am developing a game in which menu screen has sound button. It is by default is on and i want to change it to other sound off png when touched means i want to change texture of that sprite but below code doesn't seem to work.

```
@Override    
public void show(){ 
   s = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("soundon.png")));
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    camera.update();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    s.draw(batch);
    s.setBounds(w-w/7,h*asp-w/7, w/10,w/10);
    batch.end();
}   

public boolean touchUp (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {       
     if(s.getBoundingRectangle().contains(x,y)){
           s.setTexture(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("soundoff.png"));
     }
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See why your touch not detected on Sprite :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42233113/3445320

Try in this way :

```
private Vector3 vector3=new Vector3();

public boolean touchUp (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
   vector3.set(x,y,0);
   camera.unproject(vector3);
   if(s.getBoundingRectangle().contains(vector3.x,vector3.y)){
       s.setTexture(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("soundoff.png"));
    }
    return true;
 }
```

**Recommendation :**

Don't crate anonymous Texture object, keep reference of your texture so that you can dispose that texture later.