# Touching on specific texture libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

i want to touch a specific texture on my screen to start my game but my problem is when i touch anywhere it start the game

```
  public void handleInput() {
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        //gsm is a GameStateManger
        gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
        dispose();

    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2)-(playButton.getWidth()/2)+55,Pharaonic.hight/12,480,193); //corners of the image/texture
    Vector3 Point;
    Point=new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(),0);
    Point.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(),0);

    if(bounds.contains(Point.x, Point.y)){
            gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
            dispose();
        }}

    }
```

and here is the update method

```
@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();
}
```

I really appreciate any help solving this one.

Comment: You should paste your code in your question instead of as a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Sprite` instead of `Texture`, Sprite holds the geometry, color, and texture information for drawing 2D sprites using batch.

Initialize playSprite in `show()` or `create()` method

```
playSprite=new Sprite(playButton);
playSprite.setSize(200,100);   // set size
playSprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-playSprite.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-playSprite.getHeight()/2);   //set position
```

Render your `Sprite`

```
playSprite.draw(batch);
```

Bound your touch with sprite bounding rectangle.

```
@Override
public void handleInput() {

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        if (playSprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY())) {
            gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
            dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
@Override
public void handleInput() {

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        if (playSprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY())) {
            gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
            dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but i want to move the play sprite below its position when i do that it still click on the old position how i solve this

Comment: what do you mean by `move the play sprite below its position` ?

Comment: playbutton located in center of screen when i move it to bottom of screen it didnt work good

Comment: use `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY()` instead of `Gdx.input.getY()`, I edited my answer, Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42233113/3445320)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are only checking if the screen has been pressed. You need to check for a specific area being touched after doing that.

```
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2); //corners of the image/texture
Vector3D touchPoint;
touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
if (bounds.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
    gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
}
```

Comment: You're really going to have to give more information than that if you want some help. What doesn't work?

Comment: Make sure to delete the lines:
 gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));       and        dispose();
after the first if statement.

Comment: Nothing happened, i want to start game when i press play so this 2 lines do that work